# Android: Translation folders in custom resource location

Tags: android

In our application we want to use custom general path for translations.

Gradle file looks like:

```
    sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/res", "src/main/l10n"
        }
    }
}
```

But when we compile application translation is not applied. If return folder to default res everything is OK.  If I move defailt values folder to l10n - compiler does not see default strings

Android Studio new folder as resource folder:
[image]

Comment: can you change "src/main/l10n" to "src/main/l10n/res"?

Comment: I need to try it.. Let me check later